# What is the meaning of scikit-learn GridSearchCV best_score_ when GridSearchCV is used with KerasRegressor?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, grid-search

I use scikit_learn.GridSearchCV to grid search Hyperparameters for my Keras neural network (for a regression problem). The output of my neural network is a real value:

```
#generate a model (createModel is a function which returns a keras.Sequential model)
model = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_fn=createModel)

#run the GridSearch 
paramGrid = dict( epochs=[100, 250, 500], batch_size=[16, 32, 64] )
grid = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=paramGrid, n_jobs=1, cv=5)

#obtain and print the result (X, y are some data)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, y)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

I don't understand what exactly is the best_score_ member in the grid search result. Is it a gap between the theoritical values and the predicted values? This best_score_ is always negative (and quite big) on my examples, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: This will ultimately depend on your `createModel` code, specifically what loss and/or metrics you set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't pass a specific `scoring` metric, GridSearchCV will use the default `score` method of `estimator`.

In your example, you did not pass a metric to your grid search instance, so it will use the default score metric of `KerasRegressor`, which is the mean loss of predictions (according to the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.0/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L335-L355)). Hence, since you set `cv=5`, `grid_result.best_score_` is the average of the mean loss on all 5 folds.

I suggest you set your own performance metric by passing a value for `scoring`. For example:

```py
grid = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=paramGrid,
                                            scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=1, cv=5)
```

You can find a list of all the supported metrics [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter). You can also define your own.

Comment: The documentation is wrong to use the term "accuracy"; note that the first line of the docstring references the loss, and the source calls `self.model.evaluate`, which in turn (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate) again references the loss function.

Comment: Thanks @BenReiniger. I edited the answer slightly to reflect the fact that the documentation is wrong and the code calls `evaluate`.

Comment: `scoring='roc_auc'` should be used for classification problems only - here OP has clarified that the problem is a regression one.